Sign-constrained splines with `mgcv` or `scam`
I am currently trying to tackle the problem of fitting a GAM model to my data, using the following formula via scam in R:
y ~ s(x1, bs = 'mpd', k = 12) + s(x2, bs = 'cc') + 
    s(x3, bs = 'bs', m = 1)

My response variable y is always positive, and I need

The smooth associated to x1 should be monotonically decreasing.
The smooth associated to x2 should be cyclic.
x3 smooth can be piecewise-linear.

The problem I have is with the fact that I would need all smooths including the intercept, to be always non-negative, and I would like to be able to use each of them independently afterwards.
I was thinking of going in the direction of simply coding the optimization problem myself, which seemed a bit overkill. Otherwise, I also thought of the possibility of modifying the loss function to add a penalty on any negative values, but I am not sure on how to proceed in that direction.
I have also tried to re-arrange the minimum values and apply shifts, but sometimes it's not possible without inducing a massive increase in error.
Finally, I have also tried to modify the formula via
y ~ exp(s(x1, bs = 'mpd', k = 12)) + exp(s(x2, bs = 'cc')) + 
    exp(s(x3, bs = 'bs', m = 1))

but apparently this is not possible in mgcv or scam.

Constraining the response to be positive could be achieved using family = Gamma(link = "log"). I don't see why the smooth have to be non-negative, the model intercept is added to the smooth effects. Can you explain why you need these things that you state you need?

the only way I can think of doing this is to export the spline bases and penalty matrices from scam and use them inside TMB/RTMB; see https://github.com/bbolker/isec2024 for an initial attempt at this sort of thing.  Not easy though!
